# How can I evaluate whether or not switching from Maven to Bazel will improve build speed?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, bazel

I have a Java project which takes Maven between 40 minutes and an hour to build. To my knowledge, most of the time is spent in integration tests (they use [DirtiesContext](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext)). Currently, the tests for the project are being replaced by unit tests.

I want to evaluate whether or not switching to Bazel can increase the build speed. One [article](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2019/10/bazel-reaches-10-milestone.html) claims that Bazel helped achieve

- 3x test time reductions and
- 10x faster build speeds.

**How can I find out whether or not I can expect similar gains in my particular Maven project?**

This leads to another question: What exactly does Bazel differently from Maven to increase build speed?

So far I found one such difference: Maven rebuilds an artifact, if its timestamp has changed. Bazel rebuilds an artifact, if the underlying source code has changed. Hence, contrary to Bazel, it can happen that Maven builds an artifact multiple times even though the underlying source code has not changed.

But right now I don't know how to estimate the time that my current (Maven) build is wasting rebuilding artifacts which don't need to be rebuilt.

Comment: Why not simply benchmark it yourself first? I don't see how this question could differ from other performance-related ones.

Comment: First are you building on a CI solution? Second which Maven versions do you use? Are you building with parallel option? Do you use the most recent versions of all plugins? As you already writte: integration tests are taking much time? How about parallelizing them (possible?)? What about your building hardware? And never forget: premature optimisation is the root of all evil. So first step is measure where the bottlenecks are ? So how many lines of code? How many unit tests (are those fast enough?) Never estimate time only measure it..See https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-buildtime-profiler

Comment: You have given no details how many modules/how many lines of code/how many unit tests/how many integration tests you have ?

Comment: @khmarbaise CI solution: Jenkins. Maven version: 3.3.9

Comment: First upgrade to most recent versions cause there had been several upgrade related to memory and performance...Jenkins with several nodes? Building on Jenkins how?

Comment: Btw: What I don't understand is: `..it can happen that Maven builds an artifact multiple times even though the underlying source code has not changed.` An artifact has a unique groupId/artifactId/version ? If this really happens I think there are other issues in your build which should be cleaned up? Is your dependency tree clean? No unused dependencies in your project? etc. ?

Comment: @Fureeish Re *Why not simply benchmarkt it yourself first?*: Because AFAIK migration from Maven to Bazel involves a lot of effort. Before I spend my time on it, I want some estimate whether or not it may pay off.

Comment: @DP_ Simply you can't estimate you have to measure first. And you really need to figure out what the real problem is...

Comment: Try using [Exodus](https://github.com/wix/exodus) to migrate your code (or a subset) to Bazel, and compare benchmarks objectively.